# how to get a class active when hovering

Tags: javascript, php, html

I already know how to get a class active when clicking on it, but how do I get the class active when I hover over a specific area?

Here the code that gets an active class when clicking on in:

```html
<li <?=echoActive("contact")?>><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>

<?php 
function echoActive($requestUri)
{
    $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

    if ($current_file_name == $requestUri)
        echo 'class="active"';
}
?>
```

Is it something like this:

```js
<script>
 $('').hover(
    function(){ $(this).addClass('active') },
    function(){ $(this).removeClass('active') }
 )
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is not possible without javascript.

Comment: Havent tried it apparently it is `.hover()` or `.mouseover()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to simply use [CSS for the hover effect](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) (e.g., a:hover { ... }).